# Draw a line renderer by mouse then shorten it from the starting point (flight control style)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

im creating a game similar to "Flight control". right now I'm able to create a linerenderer by draging mouse over the screen and the object will follow it. here is the code:

```
void Update ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
    {
        if(mouseDown)
        {
            if (pathList.Count == lineNum)
            {
                GameObject x = new GameObject();
                x.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
                LineRenderer lr = x.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
                lr.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.Off;
                lr.receiveShadows = false;
                lr.SetWidth(0.4f, 0.4f);
                lr.material = m;
                List<Vector3> path = new List<Vector3>();
                lrList.Add(lr);
                pathList.Add(path);
                pathList[lineNum] = new List<Vector3>();
                finalPath.Add(hit.point);
            }

            if(Vector3.Distance(finalPath[finalPath.Count-1], hit.point) >5)
            {
                finalPath.Add(hit.point);
            }

            pathList[lineNum].Add(hit.point);
            lrList[lineNum].SetVertexCount(pathList[lineNum].Count);
            lrList[lineNum].SetPosition(pathList[lineNum].Count - 1, hit.point + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0));
            hitPoints.Add(hit.point); 
        }
    }
```

the problem is I want the line disappear when the follower object reaches it. so like from starting point to the ending point.
here is my code on the follower object :

```
public class FollowLine : MonoBehaviour {

LineGenerator ln;
Vector3[] path;
int i = 0;
int y = 0;

void Start ()
{
    ln = FindObjectOfType<LineGenerator>();
}


void Update ()
{
    path = ln.finalPath.ToArray();
    if (path.Length != 0 && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path[i]) > 1)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, path[i], Time.deltaTime*3);
    }
    else if(path.Length > i+1)
    {
        i++;
    } 

    if(ln.pathList.Count != 0 && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, ln.pathList[0][0]) < 1)
    {
        ln.pathList[0].RemoveAt(ln.pathList.Count-1);
    } 
}
```

problem is that even this code actually deletes oints in the line renderer but it doesnt affect anything on the screen

Comment: btw if u didnt understand any part of my question plz ask I would be happy to explain :)

Comment: man, this is messy. First of all where do you ADD points to your line renderer?

Comment: in the first script in this part : lrList[lineNum].SetVertexCount(pathList[lineNum].Count);
            lrList[lineNum].SetPosition(pathList[lineNum].Count - 1, hit.point + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really hard to read, but it seems you don't really remove points from the line renderer, plus it may have multiple other problems.

You store your line renderer component references in lrList. You call

```
 ln.pathList[0].RemoveAt(ln.pathList.Count-1);
```

in second script, which removes point in pathList[0] at index pathList.Count-1 (Pay attention, you referencing pathList[0] list with index from pathList, is it a typo? What did you try to achieve by this if not?), which is as it seems from the first script is simply a list of Vector3.

Now back to the first script, you have

```
lrList[lineNum].SetVertexCount(pathList[lineNum].Count);
```

which truncates line renderer number of points to the length of `pathList[lineNum]` (despite second script can actually remove points from the middle of pathList[0]). Pay attention that it is under `if mouseDown` clause, so it will happen only on mouse down. Plus, it will immediately add another point instead, at position of the mouse click, so it makes some additional mess.

You should consider rewriting this code. To begin with:
if you want to remove line renderer, use `Object.Destroy` function:

```
Destroy(lrList[someIdx].gameObject); // Destroy the game object
lrList.RemoveAt(someIdx); // Remove from list if we don't need it
```

If you want just to clear points on line renderer, set vertex count to 0:

```
lrList[someIdx].SetVertexCount(0);
```

If you want to remove specific point in line renderer, it is more complicated. You clear and recreate its point list with backup data (which looks like you have in pathList), so it may look something like this:

```
pathList[someIdx].RemoveAt(whatever_you_want); // Remove the point you want
lrList[someIdx].SetVertexCount(pathList[someIdx].Count); // Truncate line renderer points
// Set new points
for (int i = 0; i < pathList[someIdx].Count; ++i) {
  lrList[someIdx].SetPosition(i, pathList[someIdx][i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm sure you put a lot of time to read my messy code.